# why can't lldb > v320.4.160 find my source files anymore?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, lldb

Im using Xcode for C++ development via an external build system. If I use Xcode **6.2** (lldb **320.4.160**) everything works fine, i can set breakpoints, and they are being hit - everything nice. However, if I want to upgrade to a newer version of Xcode e.g. **7.3** (lldb **350.0.21.3**) my breakpoints aren't being hit anymore. My research so far is telling me that the new lldb can't set the breakpoints for some reason.

once I stop execution of the program and type `(lldb) breakpoint list` my output looks like this:

```
Current breakpoints:
  1: file = '/full/path/to/src/main.cpp',       line = 842, exact_match = 0, locations = 0 (pending)
  2: file =     '/full/path/to/src/class.cpp', line    = 383, exact_match = 0, locations = 0 (pending)
  3: file = '/full/path/to/src/Homie.cpp',  line = 12, exact_match = 0, locations = 0 (pending)
```

the `(pending)` at the end shows that the bp could not be set correctly. If I now set a breakpoint in the lldb via `breakpoint set --file main.cpp --line 842` I get a breakpoint of which `(lldb) breakpoint list` is giving the following output:

```
4: file = 'main.cpp', line = 12, exact_match = 0, locations = 1, resolved = 1, hit count = 0
  4.1: where = TEST`::__cxx_global_array_dtor() + 29 at main.cpp:842, address = 0x000000010027130d, resolved, hit count = 0
```

this breakpoint is being hit during program execution - everything nice

If I try to set the breakpoints on the same executable using Xcode **6.2** the debugger can successfully find the source file even with the full file path.

How can I make the new lldb version set the breakpoints correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode always sets file & line breakpoints using it's notion of the full path to the source.  When Xcode is building the project, it can make sure it's "full path to source" and what it provided the compiler (and which the compiler then writes in the debug information) are the same.  But with an external build system, they may not be the same (e.g. the build system may refer to the path through complicated relative paths, or through symlinks, etc...)  The debugger doesn't resolve paths for all the source file paths, that is just too expensive for big projects.  So if these don't match setting breakpoints by full path won't work.

You can find out what path the debugger thinks your main.cpp has by setting your breakpoint, then finding the address of the location (0x000000010027130d in the example above) and running the command:

```
(lldb) image lookup -va 0x000000010027130d
```

One of the output lines will be the compile unit:

```
  CompileUnit: id = {0x00000000}, file = "/tmp/hello-world.c", language = "c99"
```

Is the full path given here the same as the one you saw when Xcode set the breakpoint.  If it is then I don't know what could be going wrong, but if they aren't, you know the why, and that may point you in the direction of fixing it.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem actually. Thanks for the tip how to find out what path was actually build into the binary. The debugger looked for `full/path/to/./src/main.cpp` which could obviously not be resolved by the debugger. I changed the makefile src path and now it works fine.